# Padding for Global variables?

Tags: c, memory, compilation

```
char FirstChar;
int FirstInt;
char SecondChar;
int SecondInt;
int ThirdInt;


#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("- %p \n- %p \n- %p \n- %p\n- %p\n",&FirstChar,&FirstInt, &SecondChar,&SecondInt,&ThirdInt);
    printf("- %d",sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
    Output:- 

- 0x601048 
- 0x601044 
- 0x601050 
- 0x60104c
- 0x601054
- 4
```

Is padding only applicable only for structures? Because even global variables are stored with padding mechanism.
Why compilers wont allocate memory sequentially (By the order I declared) for global variables?

Comment: Don't print addresses with `"%d"`, it would lead to undefined behavior. Use `"%p"`.

Comment: This is called memory granularity and it is platform dependent. By the way, printing pointer using `%d` is an undefined behavior.

Comment: Please use %p or you will get many downvotes.

Comment: All variables are laid out in memory on relevant boundaries.  If you have global variables of different sizes, they may be laid out in any order the compiler pleases, and there may be padding between them, but a strictly conforming program can't detect this reliably.

Comment: Changed %d to %p. Thanks.

Comment: Why does it matter ?

Comment: On most processors, an aligned character can be read and written much faster than unaligned. On others, an unaligned read or write is not allowed at all and causes a trap. The compiler is designed to generate correct code and the C standard allows it to align storage for speed if it chooses. Some compilers might offer a switch to pack storage optionally to make a smaller but slower program.